# jQuery.ajax() call is returning JSON.parse unexpected character error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to debug the following jQuery.ajax() call:

```
var rollnum = $('#rollNum').val()
$.ajax({
url: sURL + "myController/myMethod",
type: "POST",
data: {rollnum: rollnum},
dataType: 'json', 
success: function(json){alert(json)},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       alert(xhr.status);
       alert(thrownError);}
});
```

Here is the method:

```
function myMethod(){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT tblontario.Address, tblontario.Municipality FROM tblontario WHERE RollNum = 211010002528200");
$json_address = array();
$json_municipality = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $json_address[]     = $row['Address'];
    $json_municipality[] = $row['Municipality'];
}
$json['address'] = $json_address;
$json['municipality'] = $json_municipality;
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
    }
```

Currently what is happening is that I am receiving an error back.  The error consists of these details:

```
xhr.status: 200; and
thrownError: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

When I look at the XHR Response tab in firebug it shows:

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://www.mysite.ca/myController/myMethod
```

Something seems to be working correctly since we are getting the xhr.status of 200, but I can't seem to retrieve the json data back from this call.  Can anyone give me a suggestion for what the problem might be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Set the header of the content to type of json...
Here is an example of setting header type.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

In jQuery 1.4 onwards the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner.

Any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

Comment: Would just like to say that I am having a similar problem, but the `Content-type` is set to `application/json`, so this isn't the only thing that can go wrong. Wish I knew what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

The server returns a redirection page with the code 200 instead of one of the redirection codes. The AJAX call doesn't redirect as the status code is 200, and it can't decode the response because it's not JSON.

Either make the server return the correct status code, or request the page as plain text so that you can examine it and look for the redirection message before decoding it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The problem was that the page was requiring the user to be logged in, which wasn't the case during my testing.  I was able to debug this by looking at the NET->XHR tab of firebug and reviewing the POST Header Response.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off BOM (encoding UTF-8 without BOM) in text editor.
BOM is a system (not visible) symbols in the begining of UTF8 file.